# How do I use results of first query in second query?

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have thousands of baskets, each with its own unique id.  Millions of balls, each with its own unique Id fill these baskets. Some of those balls are red.  My database has millions of records consisting of 3 fields, basketID, ballID, and ball color.  I need to return all BallIDs that are in baskets that have a red ball.  I figured out queries enough in last few hours to return the BasketID when [Ballcolor] = "RED".   Now I'm stuck.  I need all records with any basketID included in that result.  I'm using Access for the first time since I just realized Excel could only handle a million lines, though I wrote a series of macros and and helper columns to solve it then.  A general strategy will work and I can figure out the syntax later. Worst case scenario is I can "clean it up" a million records at a time in Excel before importing them to Access, but that will require a few all nighters I'm not looking forward to.

Comment: [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/#q=Excel+is+not+a+database)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT basketID from <tablename> WHERE ballcolor = "RED";
```

The above query gives you the basketIDs that have a red ball in it.

With this query, you can find all the ballIDs in the baskets that have a red ball using a subquery.

```
SELECT ballID from <tablename> 
WHERE basketID IN 
(SELECT basketID from <tablename> WHERE ballcolor = "RED");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a subquery be what you are looking for?
Possibly something like:

```
SELECT ballID
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM balls
       WHERE basketID = 'RED'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [subquery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664.aspx). This let's you use the result set of your 1st query as input to your 2nd query.

Let's take the query you have already:

```
SELECT DISTINCT basketId 
FROM table 
WHERE ballColor = "RED"
```

This gives you a list of unique baskets that contain at least 1 red ball.

Now we need every ball from all the baskets in this list.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE basketId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT basketId
    FROM table
    WHERE ballColor = "RED"
)
```

Some will say that subqueries are bad because they can cause poor performance. If that becomes an issue, you should look into using a [`JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198084.aspx) instead.